# Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My attempt, which is pretty scattered and likely incorrect, but just need help collecting ideas and cleaning up the proof.

Direct Proof: Assume $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$. Then, $A=B$ and $B=C$, since they are subsets of each other. Therefore, $A=C$, which implies $A \subseteq C$.

Comment: For $A=B$ you also need that $B\subseteq A$ and you're not given that. For example take $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: If  $A \subseteq B$, by definition(in the text I am reading) $A=B$.

Comment: No, if $A\subseteq B$ **and** $B\subseteq A$ then $A=B$.

Comment: I see. I read that incorrectly.

Comment: So, how can I approach this differently?

Comment: Rewrite $A\subseteq B$ as $x\in A\implies x\in B$ etc. to reduce it to a syllogism.

Comment: How do you prove that $A\subseteq C$? What do you need to do?

Comment: Have you tried starting by drawing a picture (a Venn diagram) or working out a small example where the hypotheses are satisfied?

Comment: @Yanko I need to prove that every $x \in A$ is also in $C$?

Comment: @EthanBolker I have not -- thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Ryan true. I post the idea in an answer you can read it.

Comment: A$\subseteq$B mean A$\subset$B OR A=B, just like for two quantities, a,b: a$\leq$b means $a<b$ OR a=b.

Answer (score 4):

Proof is wrong. You need $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ to show that $A=B$.

Take an element $x\in A$ and see what that implies.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to answer this question is to ask yourself at every given point "what does it mean?"

We're given that $A\subseteq B$. **What does it mean?**

It means that every element in $A$ belongs to $B$, formally for all $x\in A$ we have that $x\in B$.

We're also given that $B\subseteq C$. **What does it mean?**

It means that every element in $B$ belongs to $C$, formally for all $x\in B$ we have that $x\in C$.

We need to prove that $A\subseteq C$. **What does it mean?**

It means that given an $x\in A$ we need to show that $x\in C$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walkthrough and feedback! This really helps. I'll master this someday.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to prove is the transitive relation of subsets. The statement is logically equivalent to if A$\nsubseteq$C  then A$\subseteq$B or B$\nsubseteq$C. So assume A$\nsubseteq$C and B$\subseteq$C, now I must show that A$\nsubseteq$B. So Since A$\nsubseteq$C, $\exists$ x$\in$A such that x$\notin$C, and since B$\subseteq$C and x$\notin$C, it follows that A$\nsubseteq$B.